# Relative folder/file path in PowerQuery (M)

Tags: excel, powerquery

Given: 2 excel files (`A` and `B`) that are located in the same folder.

Task: set Source for a given PQ in Workbook `B` to reference Workbook `A` in a "relative" manner - when both files are moved to another PC the reference isn't broken.

Is there anything in `M-language` to get current folder or file path?

Comment: Appreciate if you also clarify for me if there is a sandbox in Excel that blocks PowerQuery from accessing current file location in M language.

Answer (score 4):

You need to give a name 'Path' to some cell where current path is defined

```
=LEFT(CELL("filename");SEARCH("[";CELL("filename");1)-1)
```

Then use following in the query:

```
Path = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Path"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
FullPath = Path & "file.xlsx",
Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(FullPath), null, true)
```

One big disadvantage of the approach - is that you need to Calculate your workbook after localtion is changed or set Calculation mode to Automatic.

If someone know how can we do not use cell for getting current path - it will solve a problem with modifying file and Calculation mode.

Comment: This is same approach as in previous answer, but with more details how to setup the "helper" named cell. Nice inside on how `CalculationMode` affects this approach.
Still I would prefer an alternative solution that doesn't have beforementioned drawbacks, if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

Give an excel cell a range name, like **LocVariable**, and put some text or excel formula in that cell to evaluate to the filepath you want, such as **c:\temp**

Then in powerquery, in home ... advanced editor ... edit your Source statement to use that path

```
let Loc = Text.From(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="LocVariable"]}[Content]{0}[Column1]),
Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(Loc&"\data.xlsx"), null, true),
```

or in one step

```
let Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(Text.From(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="LocVariable"]}[Content]{0}[Column1])&"\data.xlsx"), null, true),
```

Comment: Thx for sharing. This is a common approach, I've seen many articles suggesting this in the internet. Unfortunately, it has several drawbacks: the source workbook content is modified and the query becomes dependent on a cell. While in automation I'm allowed to replicate user's work, adding/modifying cell content is not an option.

Comment: you dont have to modify it if its a dynamic formula, but whatever. Good luck.